# Connect to SQL Compact Edition with Macro

Tags: excel, sql-server-ce, vba

I am trying to insert data in my SQLCE created "test.SDF" database file table, by the help of using MS Excel Macros. I don't want to convert my excel file into .SDF but want to Insert data to SDF from my excel file using macros.

Till now I have done this

```
    Dim strconn As String
    Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command


    strconn = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5; Data Source= H:\Excel files and Macros\TechData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;"
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
    cnt.ConnectionString = strconn
    cnt.Open
    Runsql ("Insert into UnitData Values(" & Version & ", " & Acoustic & ")")

    cnt.Close
```

I am facing the following error "Error 3706: provider cannot be performed, It may not be 
properly installed."

In the line "cnt.Open"
I have also added the reference "Microsoft ActiveX" Data objects 2.0 library

Thanks for the help and for any further clearance about the question please comment.

Comment: What have you tried? Google has plenty of examples of this - did you try using one of those?

Comment: I have tried the following coding.

Comment: Did you install the SQLCE 3.5 SP2 MSIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok please replace the code with the following and it will work keeping in mind that SQLCE 3.5 is installed in your system.

```
    Dim stConnection As String
    Dim ADODBcnt As New ADODB.Connection

    Dim dbRecord As New ADODB.Recordset
    dbRecord.CursorLocation = adUseServer
    dbRecord.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    dbRecord.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic

    stConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5; Data Source= filepath\file.sdf;Persist Security Info=False"
    'Instantiate the ADODB objects.'
    If Not ADODBcnt.State Then
        ADODBcnt.ConnectionString = stConnection
        ADODBcnt.Open
    End If

C_stSQL = "Insert into UnitData Values('" & Version & "', '" & Acoustic & "');"

    dbRecord.Open C_stSQL, ADODBcnt
     If (dbRecord.State = 1) Then
         dbRecord.Close
     End If

    ADODBcnt.Close
```